# PHP regex to make an array

Tags: php, regex

I would like to use regex in php to separate words and phrases out of a string.  The phrases would be separated by quotes, both double and single.  The regular expression would also have to take in consideration single quotes within words (ie nation's).

Example string:

```
The nation's economy 'is really' poor, but "might be getting" better.
```

I would like php to separate this type of string into an array using a regex as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "The"
    [1] => "nation's"
    [2] => "economy"
    [3] => "is really"
    [4] => "poor"
    [5] => "but"
    [6] => "might be getting"
    [7] => "better"

)
```

What would the php code be to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: very tricky because there's no way to reliably differentiate between the first apostrophe and the single quotes.

Comment: @Spudley: There is a difference: the first is in the middle of a word while the second begins a new word.

Comment: @casablanca - in this case, yes, but not always. eg names ending in "s" would have a trailing apostrophe - eg "I'm going to James' house". And how about the poetic "'Tis". There are cases where both leading and trailing apostrophes are valid in English.

Comment: @Spudley: True, but that kind of parsing would require detailed knowledge about the natural language in question.

Comment: @casablanca - exactly; that's why I think it'll be tricky. Unless we know more about what the text could contain, we can't rule out any possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all` on the regex:

```
(?<![\w'"])(?:['"][^'"]+['"]|[\w']+)(?![\w'"])
```

Example: http://www.ideone.com/SiG0V

```
preg_match_all(
  '/(?<![\w\'"])(?:[\'"][^\'"]+[\'"]|[\w\']+)(?![\w\'"])/', 
  "The nation's economy 'is really' poor, but \"might be getting\" better.",
  $matches
);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

(Note that this doesn't recognize hy-phe-nat-ed words as it is not specified in the question.)

Comment: +1 It matches the text as requested. You need to merge the second and third array from preg_match_all() to get the result required by the OP

Comment: This worked.  how would you include the hy-phe-nat-ed words as well?

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out /(?<![\w\'"])(?:[\'"][^\'"]+[\'"]|[\w\'-]+)(?![\w\'"])/

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = <<< END
The nation's economy 'is really' poor, but "might be getting" better.
END;
$str = ' ' . $str . ' '; // add surrounding spaces to make things easier

$regex = '/(?<=\s)(".*?"|\'.*?\'|.*?)(?=\s)/';

preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);

// strip commas and surrounding quotes from resulting words
$words = $matches[0];
foreach ($words as &$word)
  $word = trim($word, ' ,\'"');

print_r($words);
```